# Are degrees of polynomials appearing in polynomial parametrization of an affine algebraic curve relatively prime?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose an affine algebraic curve in $\mathbb C^n$ admits a polynomial parametrization, then does there exist polynomial parametrization  $z\mapsto (p_1(z), p_2(z),\ldots, p_n(z))$ such that $\deg p_i, 1\leq i\leq n$ becomes relatively prime? It is known that a proper parametrization would exist. So, will it be true for proper parametrization?

Comment: You need to be much more clear about what you mean. Is your algebraic curve a (possibly singular) protective curve? \By a rational parametrisation do you mean a birational map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to C$? By the "degree of the polynomials" do you mean for a fixed parametrisation - one can simply multiply through to change the degrees... In general such a map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to C \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is given by $n+1$ homogeneous degree $d$ polynomials - so are clearly not coprime. If the projective space is weighted then the polynomials have the correct weighted degree (so could be coprime, or not).

Comment: @Mummytheturkey ...I have edited the question...is it clear now?

Answer (score -2):

**Original question:** "Suppose an affine algebraic curve admits a polynomial parametrization, will the degrees of the polynomials appear in the parametrization be relatively prime?"

**Answer:** Let $\phi: k[x,y] \rightarrow k[t]$ be defined by $\phi(x):=t^m, \phi(y):=t^n$ for $m,n \geq 1$. You get a map of affine schemes

$$ \phi^*: \mathbb{A}^1_t \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2_k$$

whose image is a "curve". You may do this for arbitrary $m,n\geq 1$. If $m=n=1$ you get the diagonal $V(y-x) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2_k$. If $m:=1, n:=2$ you get a parabola.

**New question:** "Suppose an affine algebraic curve in $C^n$ admits a polynomial parametrization, i.e. $z↦(p1(z),p2(z),…,pn(z))$, will the degrees of the polynomials ($deg(pi),1≤i≤n$) be relatively prime?"

**Answer:** In the above construction $k$ is arbitrary, in particular you may choose $k$ to be the complex number field.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You construct a curve with a parametrisation as requested by OP - the question asks you to first *fix a curve which admits a parametrisation* then deduce facts about the parametrisation

Comment: @Mummytheturkey - I answered the original question.

Comment: I disagree, the original question was simply a less precise version of the current one. The question started "Suppose an algebraic curve admits a polynomial parametrization"

Comment: By the example above and the comments prior to it, one thing is clear that there may exist polynomial parametrization where the degrees need not be relatively prime. But then the question given that polynomial parametrization exists, does there exist another polynomial parametrization where this is true?